# Node.js server stress test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reporting, load-testing, stress-testing

What's the best choice to stress test a node.js powered server? I need to send a lot of single request and measure the delay time and validate the response. If possible I need to export data or generate graphics.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pay a little bit for the service, [blitz.io](http://blitz.io) can be a good way to go. Otherwise, [apache benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) is also a nice option, though you'll have to work a little harder for response validation and graphics.

Answer (score 0):

A [cluster of JMeter instances](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) would do the trick.  JMeter can export all the measurements and you can use Excel^H^H^H^H^Hyour favourite spreadsheet to do the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Try Vegeta. It focuses on making it easy to achieve a target rate of requests per second. I mean you can test your service's behavior at multiple requests per second. What about your report requirement, here you can also add `-output` flag which specifies the output file to which the binary results will be written to.
Link on [github page](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta).

Comment: Also I don't know about export data here, but take a look at [Artillery.io](https://artillery.io/docs/gettingstarted.html#run-a-quick-test)